# Load respond.js after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, respond.js

Is there a way to load respond.js after the page is fully loaded and does it need a call to activate it after?

My problem is that I can't edit the structure of the web app, I can just manipulate the "skin files" (those include a css and js file).

I can include it in the js file, however the situation is that the js file is loaded before the skin css file, and as I read about the respond.js it needs to be loaded after the style sheet to work.

This is needed for a responsive design to work in IE8.

Any help or suggestions would be great.

**The structure is like this:**

```
<head>
/*bunch of jquery scripts*/
/*skin js file with the respond.js file linked*/
/*skin css file*/
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: try using [setTimeout() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

Comment: Is the call to the css file at the top of your HTML page and the one to the js file at the bottom (before `</body>`)? That should ensure the css file loads first.

Comment: The structure is as this

<head>
/*bunch of jquery scripts*/
/*skin js file with the respond.js file linked*/
/*skin css file*/
</head>
<body>
</body>

As I wrote, I can't edit the structure. I just can manipulate the skin js and css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using jquery than you can do this.

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'path to ur js file';
    document.head.appendChild(script);
});
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, that's done the thing I needed. It added the js file after all the other with one little modification 

`document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);`


as the `document.head` is not supported in IE<9.

Sadly this didn't fix my problem, the respond.js script is not working for me. 

Thanks @madhurjya